# Datetime comparison update two columns

Tags: sql-server, datetime, comparison

I have a `datetime` created by SQL Server when a new job is added to the database. 3 hours after the job is added to the database and it is not completed the loglevel and the status of the job with a unique job id should be changed.

This is what I have so far. (Without checking the status)

```
use DistributedComputing
if exists (select * from sys.objects where type = 'P' and name = 'proc_dc_timeout')
drop procedure proc_dc_timeout
go
create procedure proc_dc_timeout
AS
declare @JobID int
begin
if exists (select StartDate from Job where JobID = @JobID and DATEDIFF(hh,StartDate,GETDATE()) > 3 )
update Job
set LogLevel = 1, Status = 'error'
end

go
execute proc_dc_timeout
```

But if I run the query no rows are effected. Please help

Comment: a `DATETIME` contains a date and.. a time. check out your `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: You probably want a where clause on your update statement. As it is now you will update **all** rows if  you pass the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `@JobID` is declared, but not set - so - your `IF` statement never succeeds, because any comparison with NULL value will return false. You either need to assign the value to variable, or use `IS NULL` comparison

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things ...

It seems like your `@JobID` variable should be a parameter of the procedure.  You are never giving a value to this variable.

Second, your `DATEDIFF(hh, StartDate, GETDATE()) > 3` should most likely be changed to `DATEDIFF(hh, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= 3`; as currently written you wouldn't do any updates until the 4-hour mark is reached.

Additionally, have you considered using the `ALTER PROCEDURE` syntax rather than checking for the existence of the procedure and dropping/recreating at each run?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proc_dc_timeout ( @JobID INT )
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE j
        SET j.[LogLevel = 1,
            j.[Status] = 'error'
        FROM [Job] j
        WHERE j.[JobID] = @JobID
            AND DATEDIFF(hh, j.[StartDate], GETDATE()) >= 3
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answers above note, the JobID is null. Assuming that you want to check and update *all* jobs, this might be what you want:

```
create procedure proc_dc_timeout
AS
update Job
set LogLevel = 1, Status = 'error'
where DATEDIFF( minute, StartDate, GETDATE() ) > 180
    and Status not in ( 'error' )
```

I used DATEDIFF(minute...) instead of hour, but that's just a personal preference to make sure an off-by-one error doesn't make such a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

this will not work as you not setting any value for `@JobID` and it will be `null` and you exists query will fail always

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give @JobID a value when executing the procedure and the parameter declaration is in the wrong location.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_dc_timeout
   @JobID int // <== declare parameter here
AS
BEGIN
    //...
END
go

EXECUTE proc_dc_timeout @JobID // <== put value here instead @JobID
```